# How to create complex UI component (ex- seatmap) using NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am working with Nativescript and while it's great to create interfaces with the provided UI components, I haven't found a way to implement custom components that can be used across platforms.

What is the proper way of implementing a complex UI element(directive?) in NativeScript? I am trying to implement a seat map for Android and iOS.

Should the native ui components created and wrapped for NativeScript, or is it possible to create the directive using the web technologies(HTML/CSS/JS)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create [custom components](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics#custom-components) that can be reused in your application. Nice how-to blog on that matter can be found [here](http://blog.bradleygore.com/2016/03/12/custom-nativescript-components/).
The articles above are describing the mechanism to reuse a portion of your UI and creating a separation to ease the developing process.

However, if that is not what you ar looking for you can create your own custom UI element using the native one. TO do that you will need to do marshalling. For example take a look at [this documentation section (for Android)](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/marshalling/java-to-js) and [this section (for iOS)](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/marshalling/Marshalling-Overview)
With data conversion you can either use native components directly inside your nativeScript app or you can even extend further and create [your own UI plugin](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/ui-plugin).

Comment: [Updated iOS link](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview)  

[Updated create your own plugin link](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/building-plugins)